# How to handle the current asset working directory of graphic program?

Tags: c++, cmake

I write a graphic program and use CMake to build it.
I use out of source build, but in the Windows platform, Visual Studio project directory is generateed in the build directory(out of source build), separate from the source code and asset folder. I must copy the asset folder to build directory when there have newer modifications. But this is not a good idea, because copy a asset folder is waste time. CMake offers `VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY` to set working directory in the Visual Studio, but in the Ubuntu or other platforms, I still need to copy asset folder and use some post build command. If there have some manners to handle this problem?

My folder structure is below:

```
- source
- build
  - binary
  - visual studio project file
- asset folder
- cmakelists.txt
```

My idea is when I code or modify asset, I use a working directory pointer to a specific asset folder.
When I ship a game or program, I install and copy the asset folder to the binary archive folder. Rather than when there have a modification, I need to copy the new asset to build directory.

Because CMake don't offer a universal command to set working directory.

Comment: Thansk @Tsyvarev modification.

Comment: If you're concerned about the cost of copying files, have you considered telling CMake to create a symlink as a post-build custom command?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean that you'll take that as an answer/resolution to your question? Or do you just mean it was helpful info that you'll look into and try and get back to us about with the results?

Comment: @starball i'have already found a resolution. i use a config template file to record disk path information, use cmake to pass path information and generate a .h file to use.

Comment: Congratulations. See [answer].

Comment: @starball sorry, this is my first question...

Comment: No reason to apologize! I might have accidentally as insincere by using a period instead of an exclamation mark after the "Congratulations". I sincerely meant it :) Welcome to SO! There's a bit of learning curve, but if you stick around and keep a lookout for relevant help center pages, you'll get the hang of it.